# How to customize my product url links at the bottom?

Tags: php, url, customization

I am working a project that display product image. So to get more details about the products i put link, so when we hover the image we get a link like:

`localhost/kbashop/display.html.php?name=alcatel.jpg`

So how can i modify the above link to something like: `localhost/kbashop/alcatel.html?`

I have seen on many e-commerce site.

```
<?php
include_once'includes/connect.php';
try {

  $sql = "SELECT filename FROM productlist LIMIT 4";

  $s = $pdo->query($sql);

  $result = $s->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
 $counter = 0;

} catch (PDOException $e) {

 $error = "Problem with your code".$e->getMessage();

}

?>
<!DOCTYPE html>

 <html lang="fr" class="no-js">

   <meta charset="utf-8">
   <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
   <meta name="description" content="Trouver un emploi rapidement.">
    <meta name="auteur" content="kbajobs">
   <head>
<title>KBASHOP</title>

 <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/normalize.css">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/main.css">
<style type="text/css">figcaption
{
text-align:center;
font-weight: bold;
font-size: 12px;
border: 2px solid olive;
padding-top: 5px;
}



</style>

     </head>


<body>

  <header>
<div class="logo">
  <h1><b>KBA</b><strong>Shop.com</strong></h1>
</div>

     </header>
 <div class="main">
  <div class="catalog cf">

    <ul class="products">
<?php foreach($result as $row):

  $name = $row['filename'];

  list($width, $height) = getimagesize("images/thumbs/$name");
 ?>
    <li>

        <a href="display.html.php?name=<?php echo $name;?>">
    <img src="images/thumbs/<?php echo $row['filename']?>" width="<?php echo $width;?>" height="<?php echo $height;?>"/>

        </a>

    </li>

 <?php endforeach;?>
</ul>

    </div>

</div>

  <footer>

    <div class="footer-info cf"> 
      <p>&copy; Copyright - Tous droits r&eacute;serv&eacute;s aux test - 2015</p>
    </div>


    </footer>

</body>
 <html>
```

Please any link to tutorial or tips or advise on this topics will really like saving.

So here i am putting my code for more help.

Comment: This is a poorly stated question. It's not clear why or how you're trying to change the link or exactly what you need help with.

Answer (score 0):

I've managed to achieve this by editing the .htaccess file in the root directory, adding some rewrite rules.

There are many ways of doing this depending on the URL you want to show. This URLs are called "friendly URLs". This one simple example will solve your specific request:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^([^/]*)\.html$ /display.php?name=$1 [L]
```

You have to be aware that this rules tend to get more complicated depending on your friendly URLs requirements and project size.

One advice I would add is not to name your files .html.php. Keep things simple calling your HTML files with .html and your PHP files with .php

To get more documentation about this subject read about friendly URLs .htaccess rewrite rules.

Glad to help!